# Using array_search to calculate differences in array keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to use PHP to calculate the differences in array keys of sports teams. I have two lists of teams and I would like to figure out how much each team's place has changed. Everything works well except the last two pairs 
(31. Bears and 32. Broncos) do not calculate the right differences. The Bears should be 1 and the Broncos should be -18. Why are these two numbers wrong?

I am a novice programmer, especially with PHP, so if anyone can provide any tips on a more efficient way to do this process, I will greatly appreciate it.

```
<?php

$intFile = explode("\n", file_get_contents("intFile.txt"));
$inputFile = explode("\n", file_get_contents("inputFile.txt"));

$rank = 0;
$realRank = 1;

while ($rank < 32){
    $change = array_search($inputFile[$rank], $intFile) - $rank;
    echo $realRank . ". " . $inputFile[$rank] . " (" . $change . ")<br>";
    $rank++;
    $realRank++;
}

?>
```

Here is intFile.txt, the initial ranking.

```
Eagles
Bills
Steelers
Cardinals
Patriots
Raiders
49ers
Jets
Saints
Packers
Rams
Dolphins
Seahawks
Broncos
Falcons
Giants
Redskins
Cowboys
Lions
Jaguars
Texans
Chargers
Vikings
Chiefs
Colts
Panthers
Bengals
Browns
Titans
Buccaneers
Ravens
Bears
```

Here is inputFile.txt, the changed ranking.

```
Steelers
Eagles
Rams
Bills
Patriots
Raiders
49ers
Saints
Jets
Cardinals
Seahawks
Packers
Dolphins
Colts
Falcons
Giants
Lions
Chargers
Jaguars
Vikings
Titans
Ravens
Buccaneers
Texans
Cowboys
Redskins
Panthers
Bengals
Browns
Chiefs
Bears
Broncos
```

Output:

```
1. Steelers (2)
2. Eagles (-1)
3. Rams (8)
4. Bills (-2)
5. Patriots (0)
6. Raiders (0)
7. 49ers (0)
8. Saints (1)
9. Jets (-1)
10. Cardinals (-6)
11. Seahawks (2)
12. Packers (-2)
13. Dolphins (-1)
14. Colts (11)
15. Falcons (0)
16. Giants (0)
17. Lions (2)
18. Chargers (4)
19. Jaguars (1)
20. Vikings (3)
21. Titans (8)
22. Ravens (9)
23. Buccaneers (7)
24. Texans (-3)
25. Cowboys (-7)
26. Redskins (-9)
27. Panthers (-1)
28. Bengals (-1)
29. Browns (-1)
30. Chiefs (-6)
31. Bears (-30)
32. Broncos (-31)
```

Comment: Your code works for me, I had to change `explode("\n", file_get_contents("intFile.txt"));` to `explode("\r\n", file_get_contents("intFile.txt"));` though. Try printing your array with `print_r($intFile)` to make sure it's in the format you expect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I copy/pasted all your files and code exactly as you have them, and I actually do get the intended result. I would recommend using `$intFile = file("intFile.txt");` though ( and for the other as well) because [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) does the work of both `file_get_content(),explode()` without needing to worry much about the line break style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `array_flip` to have the array in the format:

```
array(
   'team'=>postition
);
```

Which is much more useful:

```
$oldRanks = array_flip(explode("\n", file_get_contents("intFile.txt")));
$currentRanks = array_flip(explode("\n", file_get_contents("inputFile.txt")));

foreach($currentRanks as $team => $position){
    echo sprintf("%s. %s (%s) <br>", $position, $team, $oldRanks[$team] - $position);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$initFile = explode("\n", file_get_contents("initFile.txt"));
$inputFile = explode("\n", file_get_contents("inputFile.txt"));

foreach ($inputFile as $key => $value) {
    $last_rank = array_search($value, $initFile);
    $new_rank = $key;
    $diff = $new_rank - $last_rank;
    print_r("$value: $new_rank($diff)".PHP_EOL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed `\n` to `\r\n`.

Thank you, everyone, for the help!